# Experience with Java clustering?

Tags: java, cluster-computing, terracotta, jgroups

Would like to hear from people about their experience with java clustering (ie. implementing HA solutions).  aka . terracotta, JGroups etc.  It doesn't have to be web apps.  Experience writing custom stand alone servers would be great also.

**UPDATE** : I will be a bit more specific -> not that interested in Web App clustering (unless it can be pulled out and run standalone).  I know it works. But we need a bit more than just session clustering. Examining solutions in terms of ease of programming, supported topologies (ie. single data center versus over the WAN ), number of supported nodes.  Issues faced, workarounds.   At the moment I am doing some POC (Proof of concept) work on Terracotta and JGroups to see if its worth the effort for our app (which is stand alone, outside of a web container).
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 3):

[Jboss clustering](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r4/html/cluster.chapt.html) was very easy to get up and running.

It seems to work well for us.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com). It is super lite, easy and free clustering platform with cluster API. If you are clustering your application state/data, Hazelcast can be great help with its distributed/partitioned, queue, map, set, list and lock implementations.

Regards,

-talip

http://www.hazelcast.com

Answer (score 2):

You may look at Oracle Coherence (formerly Tangosole Coherence).
http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/coherence/coherencedatagrid/coherence_solutions.html

Answer (score 1):

I saw a demonstration of GridGain at our local JUG and I was very impressed. The documentation is very complete and it's very easy to get it going. I haven't started using it yet, so I can't quite say that it's working for us.

http://www.gridgain.com/

Answer (score 0):

JBossCache is a standalone open source project that JbossClustering makes use of in the Application Server.

Our company made use of it in our own custom network server, its working well so far in development, though yet to be deployed.

Its a pretty simple API, and it comes in two flavors, a flat cache, or a "POJO Cache" that uses insturmentation to keep State across servers.  Basically, updates to fields are propgated across the  network using JGroups.